# Best Options to lead with tempDB with a lot of data

Tags: sql-server, etl, tempdb

In order to load data from multiple data sources and a big amount of Data using SQL Server 2014.

My ETL Scripts are in T-SQL and it taking a lot of time to execute because my TempDB are full.

In your opinion, which is the best way to lead with this:

- Using Commit Transactions?
- Clean TempDB?
- etc.

Comment: How do you know tempdb being full is causing slowness? Usually if tempdb fills up during package execution you will get an error, not a performance degradation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They only way to answer this question is with a very high level general response.

You have a few options:

1. Simply allocate more space to TempDB.
2. Optimize your ETL queries and tune your indexes.

Option 2 is often the better apporoach.  Excessive use of TempDB indicates that inefficient sorts or joins are occurring.  To resolve this, you need to analyze the **actual execution plans** of your ETL code. Look for the following:

- Exclamation marks in your query plan.  This often indicates that a join or a sort operation had to spill over to TempDB because the optimizer under estimated the amount of memory required.  You might have statistics which needs to be updated.
- Look for large differences in the estimated number of rows and actual number of rows.  This can also indicate statistics that are out of date of parameter sniffing issues.
- Look for sort operations.  It is often possible to remove these by adding indexes to your tables.
- Look for inefficient access methods.  These can often be resolved by adding covering indexes. E.g table scan if you only need a small number of rows from a large table.  Just note that table scans are often the best approach when loading data warehouses.

Hope this was helpful.

Marius